# Is there a free or subscription based online currency conversion service?

Tags: command-line, web-services

I would like to use a service that allows the user to use automated tools to get currency rates and perhaps even provides a REST-ful API for accessing this information.

Currently, I'm using a website that considers wget to be less suitable than Firefox for reading the provided currency rates. I've chosen to break the EULA at my own risk, but wish to refrain from using services that impose such artificial restrictions on the user.

So the question is if anyone knows a decent currency conversion service that can be read "from the net" using nothing but standard, low-key tools (read: browser without JavaScript). This service does not have to be free of charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The European Central Bank offers RSS feeds for several conversion rates.

http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html